# Override property declared in framework

Tags: ios, swift

Is it possible to change some variable in my app declared in framework?

I have a class in framework (i.e module) which installed as Swift Package.
Lets name it `FooSDK`

```
open class Foo {
    open var someProperty: String = "Monday"
}
```

And class in my app:

```
import FooSDK

class MyFoo: Foo {
    override var someProperty = "Sunday"
}
```

In that case on the override line Xcode shows error:

> Overriding non-open property outside of its defining module

But property is open, so I can't understand what's the problem.

Another error on same line:

> Cannot override with a stored property 'someProperty'

Why it can't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You generally cannot override with a stored property. In this case it's a bit tricker, because the value is really just a default (since this is `var`). Generally you would override with a computed property:

```
private var _someProperty: String = "Sunday"
override var someProperty: String { get { _someProperty } 
                                    set { _someProperty = newValue } }
```

Or set the value in the initializer:

```
override init() {
    super.init()
    someProperty = "Sunday"
}
```

Comment: im totally fine with a computed property, but in that case it says: Cannot override mutable property with read-only property 'someProperty'

Comment: Sorry; fixed. Forgot that you'd need a setter since this is `var`.